# Sending a challenge to a bank card in android

Tags: android, nfc, emv

Is there a way/library to send a challenge to an EMV card (using NFC) in an android application?

I'm looking for a way to use a bank card (like a Visa card) to send some information to it, and have it signed. My end goal is to get proof that the user of the app had access to both the information being signed and the bank card at the same time.

I've tried to look around for some library or tutorial, but it seems most of the content available is on how to read/write to custom tags, or on how to use the android beam technology.

Answer (score 0):

There are specifications from payment schemes (like CAP and DPA) that describe the way to do it (usually it is done using separate card application, but technically can also be handled by payment as well) using symmetric cryptography.

The issue you'll face is how to verify "the proof" if you are not the card issuer. Without the Master Keys for cryptogram generation the method is useless.

You could potentially try to use ODA (Offline Data Authentication is based public key cryptography and dynamic methods will require card to sign something) for this purpose, but it might be problematic since depending on card capabilities you might have little field about what your 'challenge' is. It is also, not required for cards to support ODA when doing online transactions, etc. It's really hard to say what limitations you would face since you were very vague about your environment.